# Creating interface with the software without API-Possibilities

Tags: java, python

I have one proprietary software my office uses for database access and reporting which nobody likes in my office. I am thinking of building a python/Java application with a simple interface which does the task of communicating with the propriety software. My problem is: Since the software is proprietary, there is no known API of any sort I am aware of such that I can interface. Is there a way around to get through this or is it mandatory to have API to access the software? I am doing this in windows XP platform.

Comment: At what level do you want to communicate?  Do you want to orchestrate UI forms?  Does it provide a command-line interface of any kind?  It will be very hard to integration with an application that provides absolutely no API.

Comment: There's *always* an API; it's just a matter of how much work you want to do.

Comment: @mellamokb: I want to be able to open the software from my interface and use of the functions inside of that software which accepts data from my program and does the rest. Basically, I want to use my software to send the data.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: I guess, when software is propriety, they normally don't want to talk about it when they think they can make money themselves. At least, that is my case.

Comment: Pretty broad! Can you narrow it? Platform, any attempts to find an access hack, ....

Comment: An API is like door to a house. There is no easy access to the house if it has no doors... unless you break in.

Comment: It is windows XP and as far as I can see, it uses ActiveX. I don't know more than this. I am thinking about it and if it seems too cumbersome, I don't think I have highly professional programming background to take it so far.

Comment: I know you say there is no known API, but did you ask whoever makes it if they can help solve the problem? Also, depending on what you want to do, it might be easier to access the database directly instead of trying to control a program.

Comment: @MattiasNilsson: Thanks Mattias, I am also thinking the same thing. It might be easier to just access the database rather than go all the trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ask the company that makes the software if they have an SDK or documentation on their API.  Even if they have one, if you already don't like the application, this may not be much use to you.
2. If the main purpose of the application is to report on the contents of a database, there are plenty of libraries in python for reading/writing to databases.  SQLAlchemy/Storm and PyQt could probably do what you want.